# Ruby on Rails, get children of parent in template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm attempting to build a menu creator with dropdowns, I have everything working except getting the children of the dropdown menus.

In my ApplicationController

```
def set_links
 @alllinks = Link.all
end
```

link.rb

```
class Link < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :children, class_name: "Link", foreign_key: "parent_id"
      belongs_to :parent, class_name: "Link"
    end
```

And the layout

```
      <% @alllinks.each do |link| %>
        <% if link.dropdown == true %>
          <li class="dropdown">
           <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><%= link.text %> <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="<%= link.url %>"><%= link.text %></a></li>
          </ul>
          </li>
        <% else %>
          <% if link.dropdown == false && link.parent == nil %>
          <li><a href="<%= link.url %>" target="<%= link.target %>"><%= link.text %></a></li>
          <% end %>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
```

I've attempted to search around but nothing that I could find was of any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

In your application_controller.rb

```
def set_links
  # load only the parent links
  # no need to load all the links
  @root_links = Link.where(parent: nil)
end
```

and in your view:

```
<% @root_links.each do |link| %>
  <% if link.dropdown == true %>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><%= link.text %> <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <% link.children.each do |child_link| %>
        <li><a href="<%= child_link.url %>"><%= child_link.text %></a></li>
      <% end %>  
      </ul>
    </li>
  <% else %>    
    <li><a href="<%= link.url %>" target="<%= link.target %>"><%= link.text %></a></li>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```